# Passar paramentros para PDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Olá *Developers!*

Esse é o meu **Controller**

```
    public ActionResult PrintList()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult PdfJardimAtl()
    {
        var estrangeiros = db.Tb_estrangeiros_pe.Where(s => s.Tb_territorios.TerritorioName == "JARDIM ATLÂNTICO");

        return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf(estrangeiros)
        {
            PageSize = Size.A4,
            PageOrientation = Orientation.Landscape
        };
    }
```

Com esse controlador eu tenho que digitar vários comandos para cada território. Além disso, tenho que gerar várias *Views*. Eu tenho 20 territórios. Dessa forma que está meu controlador terei que gerar 20 *Views*

Gostaria de usar parâmetro:

```
public ActionResult PdfJardimAtl(string territorio)
    {
        var estrangeiros = db.Tb_estrangeiros_pe.Where(s => s.Tb_territorios.TerritorioName == territorio);

        return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf(estrangeiros)
        {
            PageSize = Size.A4,
            PageOrientation = Orientation.Landscape
        };
    }
```

Essa é a *View* que eu uso para imprimir os dados em PDF

```
@model IEnumerable<mt2414_v6.Models.DataSet.Tb_estrangeiros_pe>
```

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/ie10.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/CustomThemes/structure-table-cx.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap_edited.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<title>JARDIM ATLÂNTICO</title>
```

```
<table class="table-grey table-condensed">
    <tr class="table-secondary">
        <th scope="col" width="13%">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)</th>
        <th scope="col" width="10%">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tb_paises.PaisName)</th>
        <th scope="col" width="30%">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Endereco)</th>
        <th scope="col" width="7%">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Bairro)</th>
        <th scope="col" width="40%">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Obs)</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tb_paises.PaisName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Endereco)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bairro)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Obs)</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Esse é o resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a View principal que chama as páginas em PDF:

```
ViewBag.Title = "PrintList";
<h2>EXPORTAR LISTA PARA PDF</h2>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("CIDADE ALTA", "PdfCidadeAlt")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("JARDIM ATLÂNTICO", "PdfJardimAtl")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("PAULISTA", "PdfPaulista")</li>
```

É possível com apenas uma única *View* eu receber esse parâmetro e gerar as páginas em PDF?

Comment: Evite colocar imagens em suas perguntas, coloque apenas o código para que possamos ajuda-lo.

Comment: Desculpe. Pronto, editei.